What types of predictions are haram and is saying something wont happen haram?
assalamualaikum, I know prediction is a sin but can you explain to me exactly what prediction is yesterday i was in a conversation and i said “there no way we’ll be able to live on mars” and i just said it because i found it unbelievable so does it count as predictions and will my salah not be accepted for 40 days?
And thank you.

I upvoted because I am myself interested in an answer on how to distinguish the different kind of predictions. Should weather forecast be haram the same way that some fortune tellers tell good fortune for money? The only true way to see the future is to live long enough.

There is no prohibition in predicting anything. They are a perfectly human aspect of life. The fortune tellers are a completely different case because they are considered sa7ireen (magicians) in Islam and in their case, seek help from the shayateen who try and go into the heavens and eavesdrop in the conversations of angels and the tablet and other means. Then, as Allah said in the Quran, he sends shooting stars against those shayateen that chases them back to earth. And then they tell the fortune teller what they learned (if any) while mixing with it a hundred speculations. And then the-

fortune teller tells it to the person by adding a hundred other speculations. And thus it becomes an amalgamation of truth and falsehood. This entire endeavor is si7r and this is specifically what is haram. Any other type of prediction, including those of material worldly means that are not acquired by the help of shayateen are halal. Considering this, your salat is not accepted if you go to a fortune teller and it is perfectly fine if you, say, view a weather forecast. What is haram here is not predicting, it is interacting with shayateen and seeking their help.

@GyroGearloose There is no evidence in the Quran and hadith supporting predictions to be haram. Fortune telling is haram and I mentioned some of their details in a brief in my comments above. As a matter of fact, the companions of the Prophet PBUH used to predict things. They use to anaylze statistics and predict if a war is on the side of Muslims, or if they'll have enough resources to survive X amount of time in Y conditions.
